# QGIS reduce density of points displayed

Tags: qgis, postgis, rendering

I'm working with a considerable amount of points and I would like to be able to display only part of them since they overlap a lot and are cumbersome to display.

[image]

Most of them form a trajectory so they don't need to be all displayed, depending on the zoom level it is useful to display let say 1 point every 10.

I looked in to the rendering options, I saw you can light or darken the points but I didn't find something useful.I also saw options to display layers only starting form some zoom level (Scale Dependent Rendering as explained in [the doc here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html), but this needs to create different layers of resolution which is not ideal.

Is there a way to solve this problem in QGIS without needing to filter or process the data points in the database before importing them to QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

Your dataset needs some kind of feature ID, like in this example:

[image]

Then you can use a rule using the modulo operator `%` to fhe features, e.g. every 10th feature only: `<theID> % 10 = 0`

[image]

This is the corresponding rule-based renderer. You can add scales to the rules as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A similar idea to Underdark's, but doesn't require a unique field

Adding a unique id is easy with attribute editor and `$rownumber`, but it can be slow if you're using shapefiles and have lots of points.

Use **Rule Based Rendering**, and have two rules

```
randf(0.0,1.0)>.9
[default rule]
```

Unselect the default rule so it doesn't appear, and symbolise the first rule.

[image]

`randf(0.0,1.0)` generates a random float between 0 and 1.

```
>.9 will show 10% of your original features. 
>.99 will show 1% of your features
```

and so on.

The downside to this is that the points will change if you pan or zoom the map.

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach as well and for the zoom it's not bad in the end. Actually the best solution would be that when zooming-in, more points appear, like 10% first, then zoom and go to 20%, until 100% to the max zoom. I Think it could be a useful functionality to be implemented in QGIS itself.

Comment: interesting idea.. there's a `$scale` which could be used to alter the probability according to zoom level.

Answer (score 2):

Other way, if no field suitable for modulo filter, is create a cluster layer.
There is a plugin: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QgisMarkerCluster/

Then use [Scale Dependent Rendering](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#scale-dependent-rendering)...

Comment: I've tried the cluster plugin in the past and it didn't perform very well. Has this changed? Does it work with lots of features now?